# Making a custom keyboard on iPad, need help with some parts

Tags: xcode, ipad

Right now I'm making a custom keyboard for an app. I've set up a keyboard that mimics the look of the regular keyboard, but with specific keys that I put in. I also set up a view controller that has the image along with a series of transparent UIButtons placed over each of the keys in IB. Here's the code so far:

```
//CustomKeyBoardViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol CustomKeyBoardViewControllerDelegate
- (void) buttonTapped:(NSString*)text;
- (void) doneTapped;
@end


@interface CustomKeyBoardViewController : UIViewController {
    id<CustomKeyBoardViewControllerDelegate> _delegate;
}

-(IBAction)spaceTapped:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)goTapped:(id)sender;

-(IBAction)xTapped:(id)sender;

-(IBAction)plusTapped:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)minusTapped:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)arrowTapped:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)slashTapped:(id)sender;

-(IBAction)oneTapped:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)twoTapped:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)threeTapped:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)fourTapped:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)fiveTapped:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)sixTapped:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)sevenTapped:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)eightTapped:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)nineTapped:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)zeroTapped:(id)sender;

@property(nonatomic, assign) id<CustomKeyBoardViewControllerDelegate> _delegate;

@end


//CustomKeyBoardViewController.m

#import "CustomKeyBoardViewController.h"

@implementation CustomKeyBoardViewController

@synthesize _delegate, Keyboard;

- (IBAction)spaceTapped:(id)sender {if (_delegate != nil) {[_delegate buttonTapped:@" "];}}

- (IBAction)goTapped:(id)sender {if (_delegate != nil) {[_delegate buttonTapped:@"Go"];}}


- (IBAction)xTapped:(id)sender {if (_delegate != nil) {[_delegate buttonTapped:@"x"];}}


- (IBAction)plusTapped:(id)sender {if (_delegate != nil) {[_delegate buttonTapped:@"+"];}}

- (IBAction)minusTapped:(id)sender {if (_delegate != nil) {[_delegate buttonTapped:@"-"];}}

- (IBAction)arrowTapped:(id)sender {if (_delegate != nil) {[_delegate buttonTapped:@"^"];}}

- (IBAction)slashTapped:(id)sender {if (_delegate != nil) {[_delegate buttonTapped:@"/"];}}


- (IBAction)oneTapped:(id)sender {if (_delegate != nil) {[_delegate buttonTapped:@"1"];}}

- (IBAction)twoTapped:(id)sender {if (_delegate != nil) {[_delegate buttonTapped:@"2"];}}

- (IBAction)threeTapped:(id)sender {if (_delegate != nil) {[_delegate buttonTapped:@"3"];}}

- (IBAction)fourTapped:(id)sender {if (_delegate != nil) {[_delegate buttonTapped:@"4"];}}

- (IBAction)fiveTapped:(id)sender {if (_delegate != nil) {[_delegate buttonTapped:@"5"];}}

- (IBAction)sixTapped:(id)sender {if (_delegate != nil) {[_delegate buttonTapped:@"6"];}}

- (IBAction)sevenTapped:(id)sender {if (_delegate != nil) {[_delegate buttonTapped:@"7"];}}

- (IBAction)eightTapped:(id)sender {if (_delegate != nil) {[_delegate buttonTapped:@"8"];}}

- (IBAction)nineTapped:(id)sender {if (_delegate != nil) {[_delegate buttonTapped:@"9"];}}

- (IBAction)zeroTapped:(id)sender {if (_delegate != nil) {[_delegate buttonTapped:@"0"];}}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return ((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) || 
            (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown));
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];}


- (void)viewDidUnload {[super viewDidUnload];}


- (void)dealloc {[super dealloc];}


@end
```

I've gotten this figured out with help from [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1063/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-custom-input-view-tutorial) and [this](http://www.ifans.com/forums/showthread.php?t=201671).

The issue is using it in another view controller. I've read that you need to use a custom UIView and make it the inputView for that view controller's text fields.

What I need help with is putting this in a view instead of a view controller in a way that works. 
These are my main questions:

Do I need to put all of this code in the view instead?

Do I even need this view controller?

If I don't need the view controller, what do I need to do to put the image of the keyboard in the view?

Any help is appreciated